# Importing a function from a module in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I am trying to import function `foo` from `mod.py`

I have created an empty file `init.py` in the `C/Users/me/Desktop/NF` folder (I have also tried `__init__.py`)

My understanding was that as long as there is an empty init file in the NF directory, this should work. Can you help me understand where I am going wrong?

```
from C.Users.me.Desktop.NF.mod import foo

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
   from C.Users.me.Desktop.NF.mod import foo
ImportError: No module named C.Users.me.Desktop.NF.mod
```

Comment: the file should be named `__init__.py` (note the underscores; 4 in total).

Comment: doesn't work with  the double underscores either

Comment: oh. you are on a windows machine. then add `NF` to the `PYTHONPATH` and `from mod import foo`. (or add `Desktop` and `from NF.mod import foo` - whichever you prefer).

Comment: For `from C.Users.me.Desktop.NF.mod import foo` to work you would need to make your whole computer a Python module, with `__init__.py` files in every subdirectory, and add the root of `C:` to the path. That seems like a terrible idea. The `.` notation is **not** just a replacement for slashes in file paths.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "The . notation is not just a replacement for slashes in file paths." That was my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add The Directory to the PYTHONPATH variable.

1. Create a user variable PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C/Users/me/Desktop/NF;
2. You will need to have __init__.py to identify the directory as a python package.
3. Then use simple python import statement.

from mod import foo

Answer (score 0):

Update the PYTHONPATH environment variable  with your module path as said in previous answers and  in the python  prompt  you can, whether its picking the library from your directory

```
>>import sys
>>print sys.path
```